# How to reset the value within a class?

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe

I tried to remodel a program that i found but i cant proceed

i want to create a reset/new game

i tried calling the class and
dispose the current output after clicking the button 'new game' and creating a new output resulting the class to return to default value.
but i cant make it work. Please help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Puzzle_Act3 puzzle = new Puzzle_Act3();

            puzzle.setVisible(true);

            newGameBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   puzzle.dispose();
                   puzzle = new Puzzle_Act3(); //********************************************how to make this work
                   puzzle.setVisible(true); //********************************become new again


                }

            });
        }
    });
}
```

**here is the full code**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.CropImageFilter;
import java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class MyButton extends JButton {

private boolean isLastButton;

public MyButton() {

    super();

    initUI();
}

public MyButton(Image image) {

    super(new ImageIcon(image));

    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {

    isLastButton = false;
    BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
        }
    });
}

public void setLastButton() {

    isLastButton = true;
}

public boolean isLastButton() {

    return isLastButton;
}
}

public class Puzzle_Act3 extends JFrame {

private JPanel panel;                                                       // Init
private BufferedImage source;
private ArrayList<MyButton> buttons;
ArrayList<Point> solution = new ArrayList();
private Image image;
private MyButton lastButton;
private int width, height;
private final int DESIRED_WIDTH = 310;
private BufferedImage resized;

JPanel controlPanel;
JLabel display;                                                             //try init
static JButton newGameBut;

public Puzzle_Act3() {

    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {

    solution.add(new Point(0, 0));
    solution.add(new Point(0, 1));
    solution.add(new Point(0, 2));
    solution.add(new Point(1, 0));
    solution.add(new Point(1, 1));
    solution.add(new Point(1, 2));
    solution.add(new Point(2, 0));
    solution.add(new Point(2, 1));
    solution.add(new Point(2, 2));
    solution.add(new Point(3, 0));
    solution.add(new Point(3, 1));
    solution.add(new Point(3, 2));

    buttons = new ArrayList();

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE));
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 25)), BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3, 0, 0));                            //setPanel();



                                                                            //insert
    newGameBut = new JButton("new game");                                   //new game/reset
    controlPanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    display = new JLabel("move: "+ count);
    controlPanel.add(display);
    controlPanel.add(newGameBut);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); 



    try {
        source = loadImage();
        int h = getNewHeight(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());
        resized = resizeImage(source, DESIRED_WIDTH, h,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Puzzle_Act3.class.getName()).log(
                Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    width = resized.getWidth(null);
    height = resized.getHeight(null);

    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                                           //column

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {                                       //row

            image = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(resized.getSource(),
                    new CropImageFilter(j * width / 3, i * height / 4,
                            (width / 3), height / 4)));
            MyButton button = new MyButton(image);
            button.putClientProperty("position", new Point(i, j));

            if (i == 3 && j == 2) {
                lastButton = new MyButton();
                lastButton.setBorderPainted(false);
                lastButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                lastButton.setLastButton();
                lastButton.putClientProperty("position", new Point(i, j));
            } else {
                buttons.add(button);
            }
        }
    }

    Collections.shuffle(buttons);
    buttons.add(lastButton);

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

        MyButton btn = buttons.get(i);
        panel.add(btn);
        btn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));
        btn.addActionListener(new ClickAction());
    }

    pack();
    setTitle("Puzzle - ccuison");
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private int getNewHeight(int w, int h) {

    double ratio = DESIRED_WIDTH / (double) w;
    int newHeight = (int) (h * ratio);
    return newHeight;
}

private BufferedImage loadImage() throws IOException {

    BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(new File("myArtWork.png"));

    return bimg;
}

private BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int width,
        int height, int type) throws IOException {

    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.dispose();

    return resizedImage;
}
 int count;


private class ClickAction extends AbstractAction {


    @Override

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                            //Clicks 
        count = count+1;
        display.setText("move: "+count);
        System.out.println(count);
        checkButton(e);
        checkSolution();
    }

    private void checkButton(ActionEvent e) {

        int lidx = 0;
        for (MyButton button : buttons) {
            if (button.isLastButton()) {
                lidx = buttons.indexOf(button);

            }
        }

        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        int bidx = buttons.indexOf(button);

        if ((bidx - 1 == lidx) || (bidx + 1 == lidx)
                || (bidx - 3 == lidx) || (bidx + 3 == lidx)) {
            Collections.swap(buttons, bidx, lidx);



            updateButtons();
        }

    }

    private void updateButtons() {

        panel.removeAll();

        for (JComponent btn : buttons) {

            panel.add(btn);
        }

        panel.validate();
    }
}

private void checkSolution() {

    ArrayList<Point> current = new ArrayList();

    for (JComponent btn : buttons) {
        current.add((Point) btn.getClientProperty("position"));
    }

    if (compareList(solution, current)) {                                   //WIN
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Finished",
                "Congratulation", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        Puzzle_Act3 puzzle = new Puzzle_Act3();
        puzzle.dispose();
        puzzle.setVisible(true);
    }
}


public static boolean compareList(List ls1, List ls2) {
    return ls1.toString().contentEquals(ls2.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Puzzle_Act3 puzzle = new Puzzle_Act3();

            puzzle.setVisible(true);

            newGameBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   puzzle.dispose();
                   puzzle = new Puzzle_Act3(); //********************************************how to make this work
                   puzzle.setVisible(true); //********************************become new again


                }

            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: "but i cant make it work" is not an appropriate problem description. What problems do you have? Compilation problems? Then tell us the compiler error. Does your program crash at runtime? Then show us the exception stacktrace and the code line where it occurs. Does your program misbehave in some way? Then tell us what you expected and where your program mibehaved. Additionally, this is too much code. Please consider making an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to also include the properties of the previous class (that is, the one you're disposing) to the new class, in that way, the new class appears like the old one but with the default properties present!

Something like this would do for me!

```
public class Welcome {

    static GUI run = new GUI ();


    public static void main (String [] args) {


        run.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
        run.setResizable(false);
        run.setVisible(true);
        run.setLocation(250,150);
        run.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/hp/documents/MyLogo.png");
        run.setIconImage(img.getImage());
        run.setTitle( "Pearl Math-Whiz");
        run.pack();



    }
```

then, for the reset button's actionlistener, do something like this

```
 run.dispose();
        GUI ran = new GUI();
        ran.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
        ran.setResizable(false);
        ran.setVisible(true);
        ran.setLocation(250,150);
        ran.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/hp/documents/MyLogo.png");
        ran.setIconImage(img.getImage());
        ran.setTitle( "Pearl Math-Whiz");
        ran.pack();



    }
```

Comment: thanks for this. i got idea from this and solve my problem thank you :)

Comment: No problem @reck1ess